# PHP parse error, cant see it

Tags: php, parse-error

Error:

> parse error line 8  not expecting ','

I just don't see it, maybe been in front of this PC too long:

```
$dbc =  mysql_connect('localhost', 'xxxx', 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx')
        or die('error connecting');

$addcontact = "INSERT INTO `user`(`ID`, `Name`, `Comments`, `GPS String`, `IP Address`)".
        "VALUES('100003','john','blah','xxxxxxx','192.168.5.5')";

$result = ($dbc, $addcontact)
            or die('error querying');

echo("contact added");
mysql_close ($dbc);
```

Comment: Put a space before VALUES.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to continue using mysql and not mysqli:

```
<?php

$db = mysql_connect('host', 'username', 'password');

mysql_select_db('database', $db);

// Go on with your querying and such...

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot the function name here:

```
$result = ($dbc, $addcontact) or die('error querying');
```

Something like...

```
$result = mysql_query($dbc, $addcontact) or die('error querying');
```

... would probably work.

Even better would be (as suggested by @Chitowns24) to use MySQLi, which means you should use `mysqli_connect` and `mysqli_query` for those functions.

Comment: he needs a mysqli_query(

Comment: Before the parentheses, you should add a function name (right after the =)

Comment: @Chitowns24, he should use that, but it won't fix the error he's getting.

Comment: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

Comment: If you want to move to mysqli instead of mysql, you should change all the previous functions to use mysqli . (i.e. use mysqli_connect, mysqli_query)

Comment: Change your connection to mysqli, sorry I just said mysqli because of the whole mysql being depreciated

Comment: i changed it to mysqli but that does not correct my error

Comment: Have you changed 2 lines? Because there are 2 lines where you use `mysql_*` functions. Please make sure that both are changed in order for this to work. I've edited my answer to explain what to do.

Comment: yes i changed them all i get a different error.Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_querry()   $dbc =  mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '10304', 'whereuat')
     or die('error connecting');
     
$addcontact = "INSERT INTO `whereuat`.`user` (`ID`, `Name`, `Comments`, `GPS String`, `IP Address`) VALUES (\'10007\', \'fsfsfsfssffsf\', \'\', \'\', \'\');";
     
$result = mysql_query($constring, $query);
    echo("contact added");
mysql_close ($dbc);

Comment: Please take a look at the answer from @David Myers, he's right, you should select your database first.

Comment: Btw, the error it's giving right now is because you spelled query wrong. You spelled it 'querry' instead of the single-r version ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you are trying to specify a database in your connection string?  You can do that with `mysqli`, but not with `mysql`.

```
mysqli_connect('localhost', 'xxxx', 'xxxxxx', 'database');
```